# Tomcat disabling serialization comparison

Tags: java, maven, tomcat7, maven-plugin

I have to disable session serialization in Tomcat 7 in maven plugin. What is best approach to do it?

1. Do it expiring sessions on shutdown setting it in server.xml context parameter and providing parameter in maven plugin to custom `<serverXml/>` file?

   `<Manager pathname="">
       <expireSessionsOnShutdown>true</expireSessionsOnShutdown>
       <saveOnRestart>false</saveOnRestart>
   </Manager>`
2. Do the same as above but defining that in context.xml file and providing path to that file in `<contextFile/>` parameter?

   `<Manager pathname="">
       <expireSessionsOnShutdown>true</expireSessionsOnShutdown>
       <saveOnRestart>false</saveOnRestart>
   </Manager>`

What is the better approach to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second option would be the best approach according to Tomcat Documentations

> It is NOT recommended to place  elements directly in the server.xml file. This is because it makes modifying the Context configuration more invasive since the main conf/server.xml file cannot be reloaded without restarting Tomcat.

Informational link:

[Apache Tomcat Configuration Reference (6.0.41) - The Context Container](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context)